# Regex for replacing class names throughout codebase in Atom Editor

Tags: css, regex, atom-editor, class-names

I've been struggling with this for the last few days. I apologize if this is a duplicate, I wasn't able to find what I needed when searching for this particular question.

I have class names like the following:

`class="block underline primary"`

`className="text-center block primary-dark"`

`class="grey bg-black inline-block block"`

I'd like to search an entire codebase using Atom's regex search feature and replace every instance with a new class name. I would need the following rules:

1. Make sure the string is contained in `class=""` or `className=""`
2. Make sure it's only matching the exact word, so in the above it would only match `block` and not `inline-block` if that's what I was searching for.

I currently have this which *almost* does what I need, but isn't accounting for `className` or `class` and will return paragraphs or things not contained within a class which I don't want:

`(\s(block)\s)|(="(block)\s)|(\s(block)")`

Is there any way to do a regex find and replace in one fell swoop? I understand I might not get everything because classes can be programmatically added, but I'd like to get as much as possible with find and replace and not screw other things up. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

*edit*

I also need to account for class names like the following:

`class="block block-title blockDisabled"`

So in the end I only want to target `block` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

```
(className|class)="(?:block|block\s([^"]*)|([^"]*)\sblock|([^"]*)\sblock(?=\s)([^"]*))"
```

[**Live Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/fFBTRU/1)

From there, if you want to remove the `block` class, you would use `$1="$2$3$4$5"` for the replacement.

However, if you want to replace the `block` class, as your title implies,  then you would use `$1="$2$3$4$5 replacement-class"` for the replacement (where the string "replacement-class" is the class you're replacing the `block` class with).

**Explanation:**

- `(className|class)` - Capture the attribute name
- `="` - Match the opening of the attribute value

  - `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group

    - `block` - Match the string `block`
    - `|` - or...
    - `block\s([^"]*)` - Capture the classes after the string `block`
    - `|` - or...
    - `([^"]*)\sblock` - Capture the classes before the string `block`
    - `|` - or...
    - `([^"]*)\sblock(?=\s)([^"]*)` - Capture the classes around the string `block`
  - `)` - End of the non-capturing group
- `"` - Match the closing of the attribute value

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Sorry, I should have mentioned that class names like `block-title` or `blockOverlay` can be included that I wouldn't want to target, see here: https://regex101.com/r/xICKkv/1 I would like to just replace instances of "block" with nothing surrounding it. Is that possible?

Comment: @ftntravis - I think I got it... I added an explanation; here is the [updated example](https://regex101.com/r/fFBTRU/1)...

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This seems to be working perfect. I really appreciate the help. This will save so much time! :D